# Json date conversion in uilabel with keyValue

Tags: ios, json, nsdateformatter

Hi in my project i get the date format in json i have tried many formats.it didnt worked out.**ExpiryDate** is my keyvalue stored in dictionary.please let me know the conversion for this.I need a format like this 07/Jan/2016.

```
 cell.Expire.text=[ResDiction objectForKey:@"ExpiryDate"];

 NSString *dateString =  [ResDiction objectForKey:@"ExpiryDate"];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

My json result:

```
        CreateUserId = 2;
        ExpiryDate = "2016-01-07T00:00:00";
```

Comment: Have you used NSDateFormatter? Also, what formats have you used?

Comment: yeah i used but its not working out @ZeMoon

Comment: Could you update the question with the format you have used?

Comment: add the json string date that you are getting in key "ExpiryDate"

Comment: I got answer which i posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i juz found the answer.Thanks for all your response

```
 NSString * dateStr = [ResDiction objectForKey:@"ExpiryDate"];
    NSArray *dateStrParts = [dateStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"T"];
    NSString *datePart = [dateStrParts objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *newDateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",datePart];

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
   [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSLog(@"%@",newDateStr);
    cell.Expire.text=newDateStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cell.Expire.text=[NSString stringWithFormat :"%@",[ResDiction objectForKey:@"ExpiryDate"]];
```

Comment: What is happending? are you getting a crash ? 
Plz check if you connected the label outlet in the cell. give us some more info as to what is happening.

Comment: Nope.its not getting crash the same json value is getting printed in label

Comment: Then that is what you want isnt it?  Your question is very unclear, please state what is that you want. You mentioned that you need the exact date from the JSON.

Comment: Oh man i am extremely sorry i need a format like this "07/Jan/2016"

Comment: ohk. updating the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion from sting to date seems to be correct.

However, you need to use another NSDateFormatter in order to output the date in the other format.

```
NSString *dateString =  [ResDiction objectForKey:@"ExpiryDate"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"]; //Will convert from string to native date object
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM/yyyy"]; //will convert into string of type 07/Jan/2016
cell.Expire.text = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: Not working out getting output like this in nslog <NSDateFormatter: 0x7fb5ac853ee0>

Comment: Update the source conversion format to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: what are you logging?

Comment: What is the final output? What have you tried to log?

Comment: NSLog(@"the date is %@",dateFormatter);

Comment: The dateFormatter is an object which converts NSDate into NSString and vice versa. You need to `NSLog(@"the date is %@",[dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:date]);`

Comment: If i do that i am getting Null date@ZeMoon

Comment: Okay. Try using NSLog on the date object that was initially converted from the JSON dictionary. Also, do you know how to use breakpoints?

Comment: No i dont know.please tell me give me some link

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html